# pymongo collection.find() vs java MongoDatabse.getCollection.find()

Tags: java, mongodb, elasticsearch, pymongo, mongo-java-driver

When I pass org.bson.Document returned from MongoDB java driver function `MongoDatabase.getCollection().find()` to elasticsearch indexing, I get the following exception.

```
MapperParsingException[Field [_id] is a metadata field and cannot be added inside a document. Use the index API request parameters.]
```

Here is the code,

```
MongoCursor<Document> cursor = mongoCollection.find().iterator();
Document doc = cursor.next();
IndexRequest indexRequest = new IndexRequest(indexName, indexType);
indexRequest.source(doc.toJson());  
BulkRequestBuilder bulkRequest = client.prepareBulk();
bulkRequest.add(indexRequest);
bulkRequest.execute().actionGet();
```

But not getting such error when passing the pymongo document returned from `MongoClient().mydb.collection_name.find()`

What is the difference of theses APIs? What is the java equivalent to the pymongo's find() API ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python's elasticsearch bulk index API internally extract the `"_id"` field since it's a metadata field.

When we work with Java client, We have to remove it.

```
MongoCursor<Document> cursor = mongoCollection.find().iterator();
Document doc = cursor.next();
String id = doc.getString("_id"); // get the _id
doc.remove("_id");   // remove the _id field
IndexRequest indexRequest = new IndexRequest(indexName, indexType, id);
indexRequest.source(doc.toJson());  
BulkRequestBuilder bulkRequest = client.prepareBulk();
bulkRequest.add(indexRequest);
bulkRequest.execute().actionGet();
```